# How can I Send data to another Component without using Parent and Child Relation in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I need to send the data to "Search" Component from "SearchingData" Component. SearchingData is the child of searchData, Here I need to send the "datacame" variable data to Search Component,Can anyone Help me out this, Thanks in Advance.
I need to access that "datacame" variable data to next Search Component, So Now How i can send that Data Search Component,Can anyone Help me out this, Thanks in Advance...

```tsx
import React, { ChangeEvent, useState } from "react";

type searchData = {
  handleSearch: (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void;
  seardhingDTata: any;
  seardhDTata: string;
};

const SearchingData: React.FC<searchData> = ({
  handleSearch,
  seardhingDTata,
  seardhDTata,
}) => {
  const UpdateData = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    handleSearch(e);
  };

  const [datacame, setdatacame] = useState(seardhDTata);
  const serachData = () => {
    let defaultData = seardhingDTata;
    const filterdserachData = seardhDTata
      ? defaultData.filter((use: any) =>
          use.UserName.toLowerCase().startsWith(seardhDTata)
        )
      : defaultData;
    //console.log(filterdserachData);
    setdatacame(filterdserachData);
  };

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div>
        <input type="text" onChange={UpdateData} />
        <button className="btn btn-blue btn-sm" onClick={serachData}>
          Serach
        </button>
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default SearchingData;
```

```tsx
import React, { ChangeEvent } from "react";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import SearchingData from "./SearchingData";

const Search: React.FC = () => {
  let dispatch = useDispatch();
  //Read the Data from Store
  let readingStateData: searchReducsers.ISearch = useSelector(
    (state: { searchingData: searchReducsers.ISearch }) => {
      return state.searchingData;
    }
  );
  // Update the Data
  useEffect(() => {
    //console.log(readingStateData.search)
    dispatch(searchActions.fetchUser());
  }, []);

  const [seardhDTata, setseardhDTata] = useState("");
  // const [searchText, setsearchText] = useState('');

  const handlesearching = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    //console.log(e.target.value);
    setseardhDTata(e.target.value);
  };

  const defaultData = readingStateData.search;

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div className="container mt-3">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-md-3">
            <div className="card"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <SearchingData
        handleSearch={handlesearching}
        seardhingDTata={defaultData}
        seardhDTata={seardhDTata}
      />
      <table className="table table-hover text-center table-primary">
        <thead className="text-black">
          <tr>
            <th>UserName</th>
            <th>Phone</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Gender</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <React.Fragment>
            {defaultData.map((user) => {
              return (
                <tr>
                  <td>{user.UserName}</td>
                  <td>{user.PhoneNumber}</td>
                  <td>{user.email}</td>
                  <td>{user.gender}</td>
                </tr>
              );
            })}
          </React.Fragment>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default Search;
```

Comment: Its not clear what you wanted to do here . `SearchingData` is the child of `searchData` . So you want to send data from child to parent ? . If you want to send the data to 2 sibling components then you need to lift your state up . https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

Comment: @shyam : Here in this const [datacame, setdatacame] = useState(seardhDTata);
I have some Data in "datacame", So now I need to send this "datacame" to Search Component... How can I do that ?? and Yes SearchingData is the child of searchData..

Comment: what does datacame do ?

Comment: It has the Filtered data from this method const serachData=()=>{
               let defaultData = seardhingDTata;
                 const filterdserachData = seardhDTata ? defaultData.filter((use :any) =>use.UserName.toLowerCase().startsWith(seardhDTata)) : defaultData
                //console.log(filterdserachData);
                 setdatacame(filterdserachData)
                 }

Comment: @Shyam : The thing is here I need to filter the data, When I click on the Button, So Original Data is in Search Component, and I pass that Original  data to  SearchingData ....
here in SearchingData I did the logic in Search Data method and I got the Filtered Data..
Now i need send these Filtered data back to  Search Component

Comment: You are not doing anything with the filteredData in the search component so its unnecessary to pass it as props . Also your searchData state should be inside the `searchData` component not inside the `Search` component .

Comment: @Shyam, Yes You are Correct, So now When I clicked on the Button My data is getting Filtered and I can see that in Console... But how can I update the Filtered data in UI and Also When i remove the searched value in text box then it should get the original data back in the table...Can you give any Suggestion?

Comment: I don't see any code in the question which shows the way you are rendering the data in the UI . what are you doing with `filteredData` ? .

Comment: @shyam : I Updated my Code Can you check once?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233585/discussion-between-sundeep-and-shyam).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a state in the `Search` component which updates the state when we click on the button on the `SearchingData`. Now use this state to filter the data.

**Searching Data Component**

```
import React, { ChangeEvent, useState } from "react";

type searchData = {
  setSearchText: (searchText: string) => void;
};

const SearchingData: React.FC<searchData> = ({
  handleSearch,
}) => {
  const [ searchInput, setSearchInput ] = useState('')

  const serachData = () => {
    setSearchText(searchInput);
  };

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div>
        <input type="text" value={searchInput} onChange={(e) => setSearchInput(e.target.value) } />
        <button className="btn btn-blue btn-sm" onClick={serachData}>
          Serach
        </button>
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default SearchingData;
```

**Search Component**

```
import React, { ChangeEvent } from "react";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import SearchingData from "./SearchingData";

const Search: React.FC = () => {
  let dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [searchQuery, setSearchQuery] = useState("");
  //Read the Data from Store
  let readingStateData: searchReducsers.ISearch = useSelector(
    (state: { searchingData: searchReducsers.ISearch }) => {
      return state.searchingData;
    }
  );
  // Update the Data
  useEffect(() => {
    //console.log(readingStateData.search)
    dispatch(searchActions.fetchUser());
  }, []);

  const handlesearching = (searchText: string) => {
    //console.log(e.target.value);
    setSearchQuery(searchText);
  };

  const dataToDisplay = searchQuery.trim().length > 0 ? readingStateData.search.filter((use: any) =>
  use.UserName.toLowerCase().startsWith(seardhDTata)
) : readingStateData.search;

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div className="container mt-3">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-md-3">
            <div className="card"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <SearchingData
        setSearchText={handlesearching}
      />
      <table className="table table-hover text-center table-primary">
        <thead className="text-black">
          <tr>
            <th>UserName</th>
            <th>Phone</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Gender</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <React.Fragment>
            {dataToDisplay.map((user) => {
              return (
                <tr>
                  <td>{user.UserName}</td>
                  <td>{user.PhoneNumber}</td>
                  <td>{user.email}</td>
                  <td>{user.gender}</td>
                </tr>
              );
            })}
          </React.Fragment>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default Search;
```

Comment: Hi Shyam Please can you look into this Issue once , I am giving you the Link here : 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69024948/unable-to-post-checkbox-and-radio-button-values-to-the-server-using-redux

I am unable to post the Checkbox and Radio Buttons data to the server